# r.js is missing when I install requirejs through bower, why?

Tags: requirejs

r.js is missing when I install requirejs through bower, why?

I installed bower globally and then I install requirejs

```
bower install requirejs
```

it installs all the stuff and no error happens:

```
bower cloning git://github.com/jrburke/requirejs
bower cached git://github.com/jrburke/requirejs
bower fetching requirejs
HEAD is now at c94b6fe Merge pull request #809 from tapsboy/master
0.10.0
0.11.0
0.12.0
0.13.0
0.14.0
0.14.1
0.14.2
0.14.3
0.14.4
0.14.5
0.15.0
0.2.0
0.2.1
0.22.0
0.23.0
0.24.0
0.25.0
0.26.0
0.27.0
0.27.1
0.8.0
0.9.0
1.0.0
1.0.1
1.0.2
1.0.3
1.0.4
1.0.5
1.0.6
1.0.7
1.0.8
2.0.0
2.0.1
2.0.2
2.0.3
2.0.4
2.0.5
2.0.6
2.1.0
2.1.1
2.1.2
2.1.3
2.1.4
2.1.5
2.1.6
2.1.7
2.1.8
latest
Previous HEAD position was c94b6fe... Merge pull request #809 from tapsboy/master
HEAD is now at a77a30a... Rev for 2.1.8
bower checking out requirejs#2.1.8
Removing bower.json
2.1.8
bower copying C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Application Data\bower\cache\requirejs\ca377b0e482cd657ed20ebfa063ade1a
2.1.8
bower installing requirejs#2.1.8
```

I was expecting to find a bin directory and a file named r.js in it!

### Update:

If I install

```
npm install requirejs
```

Note that now is npm instead of bower it creates the bin/r.js file too.

What is the problem and differences between the npm and bower packages?

thanks (:

Answer (score 9):

A `bower install` will clone a git repo into the components folder of your project. So `bower install requirejs` will clone the [requirejs](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs) repo. But `r.js` is not part of this repo but has its [own](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js). You can download the compiler with bower by `bower install r.js`

With `npm install requirejs` you get a special package created by the maintainer of requirejs, who buts the `r.js` file into the package.

So the main difference between `bower` and `npm` is that `bower` links to a git repo while `npm` links to special package created by the publisher.

Comment: what are the benefits/differences between "npm with requirejs" and "bower with requirejs and r.js"?

Comment: `Npm` and `bower` are totally different things, while `bower` references to a git repo, with `npm` you have to create an npm package and publish this, so other people then only get this package. The difference is that you get only the stuff you really needed when using `npm`, while you get 2 complete github repos for the projects using `bower`.